# Regular expression in java to extract contents

Tags: regex

I will read a file that contains a list of strings.
These strings are sent to a   regex for validation
I have designed a regular expression which extracts contents within parenthesis. 
There might be parenthesis within parenethesis. I want to extract content within a parenthesis such that the number of open parenthesis equals the number of closed parenthesis. Is it possible to use regex.

Comment: Could you provide the input data, the regex you already tried, and the expected output? FYI, usually, regexes aren't powerful enough when you have nested objects (such as nested parens in your case).

Comment: The input might (hello) &&(((asnd > 345) | sdf ==34 ))
My regex gives me hello, and ((asnd > 345 but I need it as 
hello, and ((asnd > 345  ) | sdf == 34)

Comment: No, it is not possible with regexp.

Comment: Could you edit your question with these details? The StackOverflow's WYSIWYG editor allows you to format your question, so you'll be able to make them more readable than in a comment ;)

Comment: Thanks Johannes Kuhn.
I just want to extract contents where number of open brackets is same as number of closed brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comment: No it is not possible.

Explanation: RegEx is not aware of the amount of previous matches and therefore cannot check whether another thing has matched the same amount.

If not done with code as given by @akostadinov. The only way to do is to create an OR-RegEx with each possible open-Paran count matching each closing Paran count.

This will need positive lookaheads, a lot of stars and a lot of tracebacks.

It will be *awfully* slow.

Don't do it, :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would easier achieve this inspecting characters in a custom way. pseud-code:

```
for (chars in myString) {
   if (char == "(") openCount++;
   if (char == ")") closeCount++;
   if (closeCount>openCount) throw new CrapException();
}
if (closeCount != openCount) throw new CrapException();
```

Sounds reasonable?